# UITextViewDelegate not called

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uitextview

My UITextView delegate is not getting called. I set the delegate of the textview to self in cell for row by saying `cell.textview.delegate=self`. (The cell is a custom subclassed cell with UITextView property.) Nevertheless, in my tableViewController the following line does not get called:

```
  - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

Why?

Comment: Did your tableViewController confirm to `UITextViewDelegate` protocol?

Comment: Are you sure that `cell.textview` isn't `nil` at the time you try to set the `delegate`?